# tvOS High Contrast shrinking UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos, uiaccessibility

Was testing accessibility for my tvOS APP and noticed when high contrast is turned on my UITableViewCells shrink when focused. This doesn't happen with any other UI elements just all the TableViewCells.  Why is that? And how do I make it stop?

The project is in Swift 3.0